# export data to SPSS .sav file in frontend using JavaScript or node module

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, spss

I need Export data from Angular to SPSS .sav file. I have found https://github.com/tiamo/spss which I can use in backend, but is there any way to create SPSS .sav file in frontend?